# How can I get a pages content after it has fully loaded?

Tags: java, javascript, html, apache-commons-httpclient

I have a web page whose contents I need to get as a string.

Some of the content is loaded via javascript after the page has fully loaded.

Doing

```
URL url = new URL("http:example.com/");
URLConnection con = url.openConnection();
InputStream is = con.getInputStream();
```

will not work as I cannot get the content that is loaded later.

Any ideas as to how I an achieve this?

Comment: you are getting the response for that request (the first). You need a HTML/JS parser and proccessor to analize the content and then load all the resources involved. Why you need that?

Answer (score 0):

It does not work because the content is loaded later, it doesn't work because nothing is executing the javascript. You'd need a javascript engine (typically a browser) to do that, which you don't have in your setup.

You can embed some kind of browser if you really want to, but you probably don't. Depending on the use case there might be simpler alternatives.